# Why doesn't there seem to be an obvious "Cancel" to abandon an answer in progress?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

I was creating an answer for a question, while searching for the supporting CSI: link. However, I couldn't find the link and decided to just Stop without submitting an unsupported answer. There is NO CANCEL once you have begun submitting an answer.
I simulated it by submitting the following text in the space:
*I am withdrawing this answer - I can't find the episode right offhand. Unfortunately, i can't find a "Cancel"*

Then I deleted the answer. This seems wasteful. Did I miss some button somewhere? Thanks.

Comment: I find this slightly annoying too, but as DFork42 says, you are not forced to submit your post to leave the page. The annoying thing is the text is still there if you go back to the page (at least for me it is, but if guess this will be browser and session related)

Comment: FYI : http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32277/add-a-cancel-button-when-editing-an-answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The new Beta Theme adds a 'Discard' next to the button for posting an answer after the draft has been saved. This is new and helpful.

Answer (score 1):

...By navigating away from the current page?

Comment: No, that doesn't do it.  The system auto-saves a draft after a certain point and every time you get to that link, it pops up what you have already typed.  Obviously navigating away does prevent it from being posted, it still keeps the text.

Answer (score 1):

The system does autosave an answer (an uncommitted question too, by the way), but it is not saved forever. It disappears in a few days, I don't know exactly have many. As you can see in [Jeff's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/32283/168269) to the question Ian linked in his comment, this is done to prevent accidentally loosing an answer.

As aside: I actually like the fact that it is possible to work on an answer (or question) for a while. The only nuisance is that there is no way to retrace a temporarily abandoned answer! You'll have to set a bookmark.

So, yes, navigating away from the page does not "cancel" the answer, but it is not visible to anyone either and it's gone in due time.